# Facebook Sdk Android Error Building

Tags: facebook, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I am trying to build my **react-native** project and using react-native fbsdk.

However, I get these errors:

```
/home/luiz/MYP/app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/home/luiz/MYP/app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

/home/luiz/MYP/app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/home/luiz/MYP/app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.


:react-native-fbsdk:processReleaseResources FAILED
```

My current OS is Linux Elementary 0.4.1 Loki x64.

I am using react-native@0.37.0 and, because of this, react-native-fbsdk@0.4.0.

I've already tried:

- `cd android && ./gradlew clean`
- delete the project and re `npm install` it
- and try in Android API's 23 and 24.

Comment: I'm on the same problem bro, tested in MacOS Sierra with the same API's

Comment: Suddenly happens to me too. RN 0.41.2 & RN-FBSDK 0.5

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After digging into gradle, I came up with following solution.

Key is to exclude `facebook-android-sdk` required by `react-native-fbsdk` and pull in desired (working) version on `facebook-android-sdk` module - preferably without modifying anything in node_modules folder.

Fortunately, gradle offers this.

```
// android/app/build.gradle

dependencies {
    compile(project(':react-native-fbsdk')){
      exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk')
    }
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1"
}
```

Comment: I am using react-native@0.37.0 and, because of this, react-native-fbsdk@0.4.0. I'll edit the question.

Comment: For some reason this is not woking for me

Comment: Follow @atlanteh answer then. It will work for sure, until patch is published its okay to adjust `node_modules` imho. My answer show  more general solution, applicable to similar issues

Comment: @RamonJamOnCanales I got same issue but solved using this inside buidl.gradle 
`configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
        ....
   }
}`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44205756/292927

Comment: Thanks... That answer save my day

Comment: it's not working for me on react-native v0.51.0 and RN-fbsdk v0.6.3:  problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method exclude() for arguments [{group=com.facebook.android, module=facebook-android-sdk}] on project ':react-native-fbsdk' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 51):

Apparently facebook has updated their sdk [yesterday](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x) and the latest (4.23.0) sdk may have a bug or something.

You can resolve this by Changing your node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\build.gradle from:

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+')
```

To:

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')
```

I'm no gradle guy so if someone knows of a better way of forcing the version from parent gradle.build, please comment and I'll update the answer.

**  **EDIT** **

@Andreyco managed to solve this without changing node_modules. You can scroll down to his answer or click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44190896/1861047).

Also, as notified by @JuanJoseTugores there's a [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/339) in [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) waiting to be approved, so you can check the bug's progress and be notified when it's resolved.

** **Another Update** **
<s>Facebook closed the [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407479839645428/) that was opened for them regarding this issue, saying they fixed the sdk. So now all the workarounds can be removed.</s>

Apparently FB still not solved this. We just upgraded to RN 0.44 & FB 0.6.0

Comment: Editing anything in `node_modules` is greatest idea ever

Comment: Obviously you are right. This is only a workaround I found in order to immediately solve this problem. This is why I asked if someone with a better gradle understanding can solve it in the parent build.gradle which is not in node_modules

Comment: I did manage to solve this by setting `compileSdkVersion` to `24` in `android/app/build.gradle`. Btw, were you able to complite older `react-native-fbsdk` (e.g. 0.5.0)? It looks like no matter what, it pulls in latest Android SDK.

Comment: After updated `compileSdkVersion` in your `android/app/build.gradle` file, please also make sure you have the  corresponding SDK installed (Android Studio > Configure > SDK Manager > API Level).

Comment: @Andreyco no, I'm not able to compile 0.5.0  anymore :/.
you could always fork the project and apply this changes.

Comment: Trying to come up with better solution, as you are suggesting. There must be a way. Looked into `react-native-fbsdk` source, and I think dependency on Android SDK is being specified too loose. `4+` is no way to go, imho

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pulls check the latest pull request guys

Comment: anyone has a solution to deal with it in CI processes? (for an example, buddybuild)

Comment: We use BuddyBuild, but we just upgraded to latest RN. However, BuddyBuild have [custom scripts](http://docs.buddybuild.com/docs/custom-prebuild-and-postbuild-steps) you can use, like the pre build script and change the data in the node_modules (sucks, yeah)

Comment: A colleague of mine suggested the following (which worked for me!): Edit settings.gradle to override the location of the build.gradle for the project in node_modules by project(':react-native-fbsdk').buildFileName = "your location to the new build.gradle file". So you can make a copy of the build.gradle for react-native-fbsdk and store it outside node_modules and use that (and even check in to version control).

Comment: @atlanteh I did manage to resolve this by adjusting gradle config only. Check out my answer if interested.

Comment: I had to force react-native-fbsdk to version 0.5.0 and changed the above to 4.22.1 in node_modules. It was the only thing that worked. I am using React 0.42 because my other dependencies were built against react-native 0.42 (I'm using ReactXP).

Answer (score 11):

I was able to resolve this without modifying files under `node_modules/...`.  I upgraded our `react-native-fbsdk` version to `0.6.0` and then add this to our application's `build.gradle` file to pin `facebook-android-sdk` at version `4.22.1`:

```
project(':react-native-fbsdk') {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
        ...
    }
}
```

**Edit**: We are building with:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Upgrading is a working solution. However, sometimes unapplicable.

Comment: Only `project(':react-native-fbsdk') {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
        }
    }
}`  needed

Comment: @paynd That may work for some users, however in my application it was still attempting to use the newer SDK as a dependency and as a result I needed to force it in both the `react-native-fbsdk` project and in my own application's configuration.

Answer (score 5):

I just encountered this error. First, RN Facebook SDK v.0.6.0 only works for `react-native >= 0.44.0`, so you have to update your dependency in `package.json` to `react-native: ^0.44.0`. Then go to Android `build.gradle` file and make this changes: `compileSdkVersion 25` and `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0"`

Answer (score 5):

[this](https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies/issues/100#issuecomment-415262846) fixed for me

in `android/build.gradle`

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who are looking for make it work using **RN 0.42** which by now is the one with react version stable you may need to use the **Facebook SDK 4.18.0** `"com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0"` which is the one that was released by the time that `react-native-fbsdk@0.5.0` was released, otherwise you may be ending up with the issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1712442065726889/

Besides, if you are getting hard times to force the facebook sdk to be what you need try this:

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
...

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4.18.0)"
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

project(':react-native-fbsdk') {
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
      force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'
    }
  }
}

...

allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
              force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here there is patches incoming,

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/339
https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/338

in the meantime if you're using react-native-fbsdk v0.5 you could do

`yarn add react-native-fbsdk@https://github.com/tugorez/react-native-fbsdk`

I've applied the suggested changes and it's working :) but please be aware I'll no support this and wont keep it update so... as soon as you can you should go back to the official library.