# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, react-native-fbsdk

Today, I face the error mentioned in this post:
[Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144415/)

The funny thing (and the difference) is - our application is 5 months in production and we've made hundreds of builds and APKs so far. 
We didn't change a single line of code for a week (neither any of library version) and the build has suddenly stopped working with this mentioned error.

```
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:processReleaseResources'

X:\app\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
X:\app\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.    
X:\app\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.    
X:\app\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
```

Using these versions of libraries (package.json):

```
...
"react": "15.3.2",
"react-native": "0.37.0",
...
"react-native-fbsdk": "~0.5.0",
...
```

Our build.gradle (not whole), which worked until now:

```
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.5.3"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':realm')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-share')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.3'
}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Yesterday my code was working well, today when I tested, I got the same error. Maybe there was some update in the background that broke this.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144415/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name/42144590#42144590

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution. After reading all answers and related issues ([Facebook Sdk Android Error Building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190829)) and trying many things (libs updating, dependencies, lots of version changes etc.) I managed to build my app again. Then I reverted all unnecessary changes and there's what was left:

**I needed to add 2 things (iterator and line with "force") in my *android/build.gradle* file** (not android/app/build.gradle):

```
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy {
         eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
           if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.react' && details.requested.name == 'react-native') {
             details.useVersion "0.37.0" // Your real React Native version here
           }
         }
         force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
       }
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the tips anyway!

Comment: My team has just found a thing that I didn't realize - this solution is "android only" and our app still can't be built for iOS :(

Comment: I was having the same problem and your solution worked for me with react-native v0.41.2 and react-native-fbsdk v0.5.0. Cheers!

Answer (score 14):

I think this is the same problem as [Facebook Sdk Android Error Building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190829/facebook-sdk-android-error-building)

You have to change from

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+')
```

to

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')
```

in **node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\build.gradle**

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this fix was related to another bug with fbsdk update (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14225). So it didn't help me :(

Comment: It's the other way around, from 4+ to 4.22.1

Answer (score 3):

**actually there is some dependencies problem
i have faced same but i resolved it by applying these version mismatch changes :**

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

**make sure these version are same API. Means that if you are using 24 API to build then appcompat-v7 should be 24.0.+ something.**

Comment: Thank you, I've read about APIs incompatibility and tried both upgrading (all to 24) or downgrading (all to 23) all versions/APIs with negative results :( But I'll try to unite these versions after resolving the main issue (stabilizing the app) anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is found in this question [Facebook Sdk Android Error Building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190829/facebook-sdk-android-error-building)

I've also forked a repo and provided all these changes to make it run with RN 0.42. You can install it by typing `yarn add https://github.com/kidnapkin/react-native-fbsdk.git`

Comment: Thank you! This comment helped me the most! Mainly by linking related question, where i found solution, see below.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened after libs updating, adding dependencies, version changes etc. All you need is match Sdk versions of your project, and package you just added or has been updated.

1. Go to android/app/build.gradle

   ```
   android {
     compileSdkVersion 25
     buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

     defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 25
   ```

   }
2. Go to node_modules/your-package/android/build.gradle

   ```
   android {
     compileSdkVersion 25
     buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

     defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 25
   ```

If problem will not be resolved yet, then check other packages from package.json

Thats it. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I solve that problem by only modifying android/app/build.gradle file.
You need to modify the compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion as follows.

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```