# react-native not running on Android post update

Tags: android, react-native

Did a react-native-git-upgrade today. And then I ended up with below errors.

```
:app:processDebugResources
/../android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/../app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

/../android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/../app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
```

The suggestions already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202072/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190829/facebook-sdk-android-error-building)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. My build.gradle has

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

And

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit here: [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202072/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name).

You've already linked this above, but don't seem to have indicated that you've tried the solution(s).

This is an issue with `react-native-fbsdk`, until they fix it you'll need to do the following:

`android/build.gradle`:

```
project(':react-native-fbsdk') {
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
       force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
     }
  }
}
```

`android/app/build.gradle`:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
```

The above works for our project, please give it a try. You'll of course need the v24 SDK, Build Tools and Support Repository.

Comment: Yep, no problem, should work with anything from 24.0 and above. Did you need the project override?