# React Native run on android: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion, react-native-navigation

I found some similar questions but could not find a solution for this problem. I am using react-native-cli and keep receiving an error when I try to run on android simulator. I tried both using Android Studio and Genymotion simulators, the error seems to be the same.

I tried to delete the build folder and run again, but no success.

Here some details:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/udemy/react-native/template_navigation_firebase_auth/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/valu
es-v24.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Bu
tton.Colored'.


:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: This is likely due to `+` dependency in `react-native-fbsdk`. Please see my answer here. This should solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332749/react-native-not-running-on-android-post-update/44332935#44332935

Comment: HI @G0dsquad, thanks for your reply. I think the issue is related to react-native-navigation. I tried to run their bootstrap app and it created a few problems. if I try to run another test app it works well, with no need to make the modifications you pointed out.

Comment: I was hoping you'd had the same problem as me, seems there are many ways to get the same error!