# :app:processDebugResources FAILED error when building react-native android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm getting a `:app:processDebugResources FAILED` error when running `react-native run-android` and I have no clue on how to fix it, I tried some of the things they mention here: [Execution failed app:processDebugResources Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio) but it didn't help.

Here's a stack trace:

```
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:185)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
        ... 70 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:873)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:178)
        ... 77 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 'C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe' with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar -M C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.conv.android -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:871)
        ... 78 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 'C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe' with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar -M C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.conv.android -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Conv\Conv2\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:75)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:60)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:47)
        ... 9 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Are you using the package `react-native-fbsdk` by any chance?

Comment: Yes I tried to add it. I followed the instructions they gave on their repo for adding it. @RodolfoPerottoni

Comment: Check this https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `react-native-fbsdk` you're probably facing this issue:

[Facebook Sdk Android Error Building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190829/facebook-sdk-android-error-building)

I had the same issue and fixed it by following Andreyco's answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44190896/2983125

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't build.. I'm getting this if you're interested: https://pastebin.com/U9CY7nNb Do you know if it's possible to login into facebook without this package?

Comment: This is a completely different problem. You have to open the file described in the error and import the "Intent" class from the Android SDK in your class.

Comment: in what class should I add that import?

Comment: The one described in the error. `android\app\src\main\java\com\conv\MainApplication.java`